# How to make an array(brackets) as template parameters?

Tags: c++

Here is my code

```
template<typename B>
class carl_ptr{
public:
    B* ptr;
    carl_ptr(B* asd){
        ptr = asd;
    }


    ~carl_ptr(){
        delete ptr;
    }
};

class dummy{
public:
    ~dummy(){
    std::cout<<"destructed"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{

carl_ptr<int> carl(new int[10]);

//std::unique_ptr<int[]> asd(new int[10]);     //int[] parameter like this?
}
```

I am trying to make my own smart_pointer for research/practice purposes.

Questions:

1.) What difference does "int[]" do vs "int" as parameters?
Because both cases works for the unique_ptr and i want to know 
if they matter.

2) How do i make my template accept "int[]" as parameter?

3) Are there any ways to know what kind of object i am deleting(if it's an array or not)? because 
there are 2 kinds of delete, the `delete[]` and `delete` and i want to differentiate so i will know what to apply.

Comment: 1. `[]` declares an array. 2. You need to partially specialize your template (`template <class T> my_ptr<T[]>` etc). 3. see #2.

Comment: So that means i will have to make 2 instances in order to partly specialize my template?

Comment: Yes, you will. [see this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01099_source.html) for an example.